# Using haml & sass with Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, haml, sass

Most questions I've seen addressing is seem to be a year to two old, so I'd be interested in finding out whether there have been any Improvements to using haml and sass with Wordpress.

Is phamlp something that's continuing to be developed, or are you using another option to incorporate haml and sass into your templates? Thoughts appreciated,

Don

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one [previous thread on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043777/wordpress-with-haml-sass).

The source for phamlp hasn't been updated since 2010, however it has been [forked on Github](https://github.com/goncaloesteves/phamlp). As an alternative to using Haml, I would suggest investigating an [implementation of Jade in PHP](https://github.com/everzet/jade.php).