# Working with CodeKit and haml/PHP

Tags: php, haml

in my latests projects I have use Rails. Now I have to do something in PHP (which I actually hate, or love too much Ruby syntax).

So now I am very used to work with Sass and haml, which I also love. So I bought [CodeKit](http://incident57.com/codekit/) for doing things outside rails framework.

Wanted just to know if there is any option for use haml in PHP files, or PHP in haml files, and that the file compiles with CodeKit, even having PHP.

Comment: If I set the output path to *.php it would work fine, would compile haml to html and let PHP code , but then I have a syntax color issue on SublimeText (can just choose between haml or PHP syntax). And there's no package for php/haml!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:plain` filter to preserve the php, it does not parse the filtered text. This is useful when you need to keep multiple lines of php.

ex:

```
:plain
  <?php foreach ($es as $e) {
    echo $e;
  } ?>
```

I have not heard about any haml/php color syntax for Sublime Text 2 yet.

There is another setting that can be useful for working with php : check the don't escape HTML character in the HAML config on Codekit : http://d.pr/i/4pmv

This will manage with that

```
%form#booking_log{:name => "booking_log", :method => "post", :action => "<?=$this->action('bookingGetLog')?>"}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very late reply, just found this question when searching myself.

**In addition to Kevin's reply above:**

You can automatically convert the html to php by simply setting the output path for that particular file, and then specifying the extension.

1. Right click your HAML or HTML
2. "Set output path..."
3. "Output filename and extension"

Change it from `index.html` or `index.haml` to `index.php`.